# Android reading SD External is not working

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage

I am trying to read some files from my external SD.

```
final File externalStorage =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

String list = "";//
list+= "Listing all the files in SD: "  + externalStorage.getAbsolutePath() + "\n";
Log.i("VVV", list);

for (File file: externalStorage.listFiles()) {
    Log.i("VVV", file.getAbsolutePath());
    list += file.getAbsolutePath() + "\n";
}
```

I am trying to read my external SD. I do not why always get the /emulate/0 path instead of /storage/sdcard.

it is the output for the above code:

```
01-22 19:07:55.852 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: Listing all the files in SD: /storage/emulated/0
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Samsung
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/.face
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Music
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Podcasts
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Ringtones
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Alarms
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Notifications
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Movies
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Download
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Documents
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Android
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/SMemo
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/ATT Locker
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/.wildtangent
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/.profig.os
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/com.facebook.orca
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/.thumbnails
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Facebook Messenger
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/PhotoEditor
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/.facebook_cache
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Playlists
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/wdh_update
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/Skai
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/com.qisi.sdk.file
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/fujifilm
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/com.facebook.katana
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/IMO
01-22 19:07:55.862 23991-23991/forkandjoin.tvplayer I/VVV: /storage/emulated/0/ialog.txt
```

So I do not know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html). Your code is accessing external storage. You do not have filesystem access to arbitrary locations on removable storage. You are welcome to use [the Storage Access Framework](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/05/03/storage-access-framework-faq.html) to ask the user to open a document, and the user can choose a document on removable storage.

Comment: So Google doesn't provide any API for Removable Storage? What happen if I want to search or manage all the videos or information in my SD removable storage? Any suggestions?

Comment: @Robert: Use `MediaStore` to work with media, including on removable storage.

Comment: I am working in a project. The customers want to save all the data related with videos in SD External (Removable Storage). If they wanna update the content of the SD removed and put the new one. But with MediaStore I have search trough all the videos in the Device and then choose what videos are the right ones. Wow it is gonna be a lot of work. So is not there a way to know the data on Removable storage?

Comment: @Robert: use the Storage Access Framework, as I mentioned in my answer. Or, use `getExternalFilesDirs()`. Or, use `StorageManager` on Android 7.0+.